# Need Background Location Permission

Tags: flutter, permissions, location, settings

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOtyb.pngWhile debugging App for ios in flutter, I am getting this message "Need Background Location permission. Need Location Permission to track your Location. Please follow the steps: Settings" on simulator.How to resolve it?I tried to set the location permission in settings options in iPhone Simulator.I didn't found anything in settings of iPhone Simulator

Answer (score 0):

for iOS background location you need to add the following into Info.plist file then it'll ask for permission to use location **always** .

Normal location permission will only ask you to get location **while in use** in the foreground.

### Location Permissions

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>We need you location even if the app is in the background</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>We need to  access your location </string>
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>location</string>
</array>
```